# Reading a text file that contains several CSV-like tables

Tags: c#, csv, file-structure

I wrote some extension methods to read CSV-styled text directly into a datatable or dataset or write them to this format. Is it right to use the methods as extensions or should I create a separate class that contains this functionality, and so on?

Formats explained:

The `ReadFromCsv` and `WriteToCsv` will work with a normal CSV style like:

> ```
> Column1;Column2;Column3;...
> Value11;Value12;Value13;...
> Value21;Value22;Value23;...
> ```

The `ReadFromSectionedCsv` and `WriteToSectionedCsv` methods use a format like this:

> ```
> [Table1]
> Column1;Column2;Column3;...
> Value11;Value12;Value13;...
> Value21;Value22;Value23;...
>
> [Table2]
> Column1;Column2;Column3;...
> Value11;Value12;Value13;...
> Value21;Value22;Value23;...
> ```

where each table is read to a separate `DataTable` in the `DataSet`.

```cs
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace CsvExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Erweiterungen für die Klassen System.Data.DataTable und System.Data.DataSet
    /// zum einlesen von an CSV angelehnten Daten direkt in eine Instanz dieser Typen
    /// </summary>
    public static class DataCsvExtension
    {
        //Trennzeichen der einzelnen Spalten
        private const char SEPERATOR = ';';

        /// <summary>
        /// Liest die Daten einer CSV Datei ein
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="table">DataTable object</param>
        /// <param name="filepath">Pfad zur CSV Datei</param>
        public static void ReadFromCsv(this DataTable table, string filepath)
        {
            using (Stream filestream = File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                table.ReadFromCsv(filestream);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Liest die Daten einer CSV Datei ein
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="table">DataTable object</param>
        /// <param name="filestream">Stream der CSV Datei</param>
        public static void ReadFromCsv(this DataTable table, Stream filestream)
        {
            table.Clear();

            Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8; //Encoding.Default;
            //if (Utf8Checker.IsUtf8(filestream))
            //    encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filestream, encoding);
            string line = sr.ReadLine();

            //empty line is considered the end of the table
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                return;

            string[] array = line.Split(SEPERATOR);


            foreach (string value in array)
            {
                DataColumn dataColumn = new DataColumn(value.Trim())
                {
                    Caption = value.Trim()
                };
                table.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
            }
            table.NewRow();

            while (sr.Peek() > -1)
            {
                line = sr.ReadLine();

                if (line == null
                    || (line.Trim() == "" || !line.Contains(SEPERATOR)
                        || String.IsNullOrEmpty(line.Replace(';', ' ').Trim())))
                    continue;
                array = line.Split(SEPERATOR);

                int count = table.Columns.Count;
                if (array.Length < count)
                {
                    string[] newArray = new string[count];
                    for (int s = 0; s<array.Length;s++)
                    {
                        newArray[s] = array[s];
                    }
                    for( int s = array.Length; s<count;s++)
                    {
                        newArray[s] = "";
                    }
                    array = newArray;

                }
                if (array.Length > table.Columns.Count)
                {
                    //More Values than Columns found
                    throw new Exception(
                        String.Format(
                            "Fehlerhafte Zeile: Wertanzahl entspricht nicht der Anzahl der Spalten: {0}", line));
                }
                table.Rows.Add(array);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Liest die Daten aus einer sektionierten CSV Datei in das DataSet
        /// Format der CSV-Datei:
        ///     [Tabellenname1]
        ///     Spalte1;Spalte2;Spalte3
        ///     Wert11;Wert12;Wert13
        ///     Wert21;Wert22;Wert23
        ///     ....
        ///     WertN1;WertN2;WertN3
        ///     [Tabellenname2]
        ///     Spalte1;Spalte2...
        ///     ...
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dataset">DataSet object</param>
        /// <param name="filepath">Pfad zur CSV Datei</param>
        public static void ReadFromSectionedCsv(this DataSet dataset, string filepath)
        {
            const string PATTERN = @"
^                           # Beginning of the line
((?:\[)                     # Section Start
(?:[ ]*)
(?<Section>[^\]^ ]*)         # Actual Section text into Section Group
(?:[ ]*)
(?:\])                    # Section End then EOL/EOB
(?:[ ;]*)
(?:[\r\n]{1,})
(?<Data>[^\[]*)
(?:[\r\n]{0,})
)";
            dataset.Clear();
            using (Stream filestream = File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8; //Encoding.Default;
                //if (Utf8Checker.IsUtf8(filestream))
                //    encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                string fileContetnt;
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filestream, encoding))
                {
                    fileContetnt = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }

                var match = Regex.Matches(fileContetnt, PATTERN,
                    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline);
                foreach (Match m in match)
                {
                    var sectionmatch = m.Groups["Section"];
                    var datamatch = m.Groups["Data"];
                    //Refactor: Is there a Better way to read the Tables of a Section?
                    using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) 
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                        {
                            writer.Write(datamatch.Value);
                            writer.Flush();
                            stream.Position = 0;
                            dataset.Tables.Add(sectionmatch.Value).ReadFromCsv(stream);
                        }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Schreibt die Daten der DataTable als neue CSV Datei
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="table">DataTable object</param>
        /// <param name="filepath">Pfad zur CSV Datei</param>
        public static void WriteToCsv(this DataTable table, string filepath)
        {
            using (Stream filestream = File.Open(filepath, FileMode.CreateNew))
            {
                table.WriteToCsv(filestream);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Schreibt die Daten der DataTable im CSV Format in den angegebenen Stream
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="table">DataTable object</param>
        /// <param name="filestream">Stream der CSV Datei</param>
        public static void WriteToCsv(this DataTable table, Stream filestream)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filestream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                int numberOfColumns = table.Columns.Count;

                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++)
                {
                    sw.Write(table.Columns[i]);
                    if (i < numberOfColumns - 1)
                        sw.Write(SEPERATOR);
                }

                foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine();
                    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++)
                    {
                        sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());

                        if (i < numberOfColumns - 1)
                            sw.Write(SEPERATOR);
                    }
                }
                sw.Flush();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Schreibt die Daten des DataSet als neue sektionierte CSV Datei
        /// Format der CSV-Datei:
        ///     [Tabellenname1]
        ///     Spalte1;Spalte2;Spalte3
        ///     Wert11;Wert12;Wert13
        ///     Wert21;Wert22;Wert23
        ///     ....
        ///     WertN1;WertN2;WertN3
        ///     [Tabellenname2]
        ///     Spalte1;Spalte2...
        ///     ...
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dataset">DataSet object</param>
        /// <param name="filepath">Pfad zur CSV Datei</param>
        public static void WriteToSectionedCsv(this DataSet dataset, string filepath)
        {
            using (Stream filestream = File.Open(filepath, FileMode.CreateNew))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filestream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    foreach (DataTable table in dataset.Tables)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("[{0}]", table.TableName);
                        int numberOfColumns = table.Columns.Count;

                        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++)
                        {
                            sw.Write(table.Columns[i]);
                            if (i < numberOfColumns - 1)
                                sw.Write(SEPERATOR);
                        }

                        foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine();
                            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++)
                            {
                                sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());

                                if (i < numberOfColumns - 1)
                                    sw.Write(SEPERATOR);
                            }
                        }
                        sw.WriteLine();
                    }
                    sw.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Questions:

- How would you handle malformed files?
- Are all the `Stream`s and `using`s necessary?
- How can I organize the code with respect to easy unit testing?
- What parts of the code would you parametrize? For instance, letting the user select the separating `char`.

Comment: Can you share an example of how you are using the extension methods? I assume something like `var table = new DataTable(); table.ReadFromCsv("C:\some-file.csv");`

Comment: This is exactly how its used. Still don't know if it was a good idea cause you always have to create a DataTable or DataSet yourself and I still couldn't think of a situation you use an existing DataTable with it. Maybe the methods should create a DataTable themself and should not be extension mehtods

Comment: Hey - if you are reading CSV files you might want to check out: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

It's a great project if you are reading in CSV data.

Comment: Comments in German. Good thing nobody actually RTFMs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> if (array.Length < count)
> {
>     string[] newArray = new string[count];
>     for (int s = 0; s<array.Length;s++)
>     {
>         newArray[s] = array[s];
>     }
>     for( int s = array.Length; s<count;s++)
>     {
>         newArray[s] = "";
>     }
>     array = newArray;
>
> }
> ```

You can use [`Array.Resize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to simplify this.

```
if (array.Length < count)
{
    var length = array.Length;
    Array.Resize(ref array, count);
    for (var i = length; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

---

> ```
> if (line == null
>     || (line.Trim() == "" || !line.Contains(SEPERATOR)
>         || String.IsNullOrEmpty(line.Replace(';', ' ').Trim())))
> ```

I think you want to be using `SEPERATOR` instead of `;` here.

---

> ```
> sw.WriteLine("[{0}]", table.TableName);
> int numberOfColumns = table.Columns.Count;
>
> for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++)
> {
>     sw.Write(table.Columns[i]);
>     if (i < numberOfColumns - 1)
>         sw.Write(SEPERATOR);
> }
>
> foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
> {
>     sw.WriteLine();
>     for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++)
>     {
>         sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
>
>         if (i < numberOfColumns - 1)
>             sw.Write(SEPERATOR);
>     }
> }
> sw.WriteLine();
> ```

This can be simplified.

```
writer.WriteLine("[{0}]", table.TableName);
writer.WriteLine(string.Join(SEPERATOR.ToString(), table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()));
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    writer.WriteLine(string.Join(SEPERATOR.ToString(), row.ItemArray));
}
```

---

> How can I organize the code with respect to easy unit testing?

I would consider making the methods take a `TextReader` (`TextWriter`) instead of a `Stream`. You can then pass a `StringReader` (`StringWriter`) from your unit tests, while client code will normally pass a `StreamReader` (`StreamWriter`). This will also allow client code to choose the encoding (which they really should be doing) instead of being forced to use UTF-8.

Another reason to consider doing this is that someone calling `WriteToCsv` might want to write to the stream after the call returns. But they will get an exception, since `StreamWriter` disposes of the underlying stream. For example, we get an `ObjectDisposedException` when we call `WriteByte` here:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
    }
    stream.WriteByte(0);
}
```

Finally, it makes code re-use a bit easier. For instance, `WriteToSectionedCsv` can be written in terms of `WriteToCsv`.

```
public static void WriteToCsv(this DataTable table, TextWriter writer)
{
    writer.WriteLine(string.Join(SEPERATOR.ToString(), table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()));
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(string.Join(SEPERATOR.ToString(), row.ItemArray));
    }
}

public static void WriteToSectionedCsv(this DataSet dataSet, TextWriter writer)
{
    foreach (DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
    {
        writer.WriteLine("[{0}]", table.TableName);
        table.WriteToCsv(writer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the code got so much shorter through your tipps. Especially the TextReader/TextWriter part simplifies the code alot

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> var match = Regex.Matches(fileContetnt, PATTERN,
>     RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline);
> ```

Because `Regex.Matches()` returns a `MatchCollection` you should use the plural form for naming the variable.

```
var matches = ...
```

---

> ```
> Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8; //Encoding.Default;
> //if (Utf8Checker.IsUtf8(filestream))
> //    encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
> ```

Commented code is dead code and should be removed to improve readability.

---

For naming variables you should ensure that they are spelled correctly.

> ```
> string fileContetnt;
> ```

should be

```
string fileContent;
```

---

You should stick to the style you have choosen. You use sometimes braces `{}` for single statement `if` and sometimes you don't.

You sometimes stack `using` constructs and sometimes you don't.

---

You should consider to change the xml doxumentation from german to english. Assume you will hire a developer which comes from outside of Germany and only speaks english.

---

Instead of using `Peek()`

> ```
> while (sr.Peek() > -1)
> {
>     line = sr.ReadLine();
> ```

you can also check if `line != null` like

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
```

this makes the check for `line == null` in the following `if` condition redundant.

---

Because extension methods can also be called like normal methods, you should add a null check like

```
    public static void ReadFromCsv(this DataTable table, string filepath)
    {
        if (table == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("table");
        }
        using (Stream filestream = File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            table.ReadFromCsv(filestream);
        }
    }
```

---

Because you use the variable `encoding` only once, you can simplify the creation of the `StreamReader` like

```
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filestream, Encoding.UTF8);
```

---

The call to `table.NewRow();` is redundant, because you don't use the returned `DataRow` because you are using the overloaded [`DataRowCollection.Add()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wwak56%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which takes an `object[]` instead of a `DataRow`. You can safely remove it.

Comment: Thanks, added the argument checks. removed the whole encoding part and got rid of Peek, table.NewRow and most of the usings

Answer (score 5):

Two quick remarks:

- There's a typo, it should be Sep**a**rator, not Sep**e**rator.
- Microsoft's standard is to [use PascalCase for constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Thanks fixed the typo. But still got to think about the naming coventions. I like to see the difference between a constant and a property by looking at the name.

Answer (score 3):

On top of what has already been mentioned:

Your implementation will break if any of the column names or values contains a ';'. Proper CSV parsing is a tad harder than most people naively assume. Now this may or may not matter because you might say *"The data will never ever contain `;`"* however given the number of times this phrase was uttered and then proven wrong you should consider actually either implementing a proper CSV parser or use an of-the-shelf one. It's not that hard and will protect you against [Murphy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law) (at least for that case).

Comment: Well i continued someone elses project wich already contained a far worse implementation of the csv parsing and didn't think about just throwing it away and use a CSV Parsing Library instead. But reading your text, i can't agree more with you. Is there any project you can recommend?

Comment: @BoeseB At the company I'm working at we rolled our own but this one https://www.nuget.org/packages/Net.Code.Csv/ seems to handle most cases (including quotes inside quoted values)